# Correctly quote array that is being passed indirectly via another command

Tags: bash, quoting, array, arguments

I need to pass an array of filenames to a command, preserving proper quoting. So far, so good. Unfortunately the command is actually a sub-command that is, in turn, invoked by another command. Concretely, the command is:

```bsh
git filter-branch --index-filter \
    'git rm -rf --cached ‹file1› ‹file2›…' \
    HEAD
```

For simplicity, I’m going to replace this in the following by a simpler command that exhibits the same problem:

```bsh
printf '%s\n' 'cmd file1 file2…'
```

Now I’ve got an array `files=('a b' c)`. My desired result is that the above command prints *in a single line*, and individually quotes every token after `cmd` as necessary (e.g. when there’s a space).

It works if I manually expand and quote the file names:

```bsh
$ printf '%s\n' 'cmd '\''a b'\'' c'
→ cmd 'a b' c
```

(Alternatively I could mix single and double quotes to achieve the same result.)

But it no longer works if I am trying to pass an array:

1. ```bsh
   $ (set -x; printf '%s\n' "cmd '${files[@]}'")
   + printf '%s\n' 'cmd '\''a b' 'c'\'''
   → cmd 'a b
   c'
   ```
2. ```bsh
   $ (set -x; printf '%s\n' 'cmd '\'"${files[@]}"\')
   + printf '%s\n' 'cmd '\''a b' 'c'\'''
   → cmd 'a b
   c'
   ```
3. ```bsh
   $ (set -x; printf '%s\n' 'cmd '"${files[@]}")
   + printf '%s\n' 'cmd a b' c
   → cmd a b
   c
   ```

I’m not surprised (3) doesn’t work (and it’s only included for completeness). Based on the output of `set -x`, the shell correctly quotes the individual array elements in (1) and (2) and it even puts escaped quotes around the whole thing. But then it breaks apart the individually quoted items. Is there a way to prevent this?

---

Incidentally, Shellcheck (SC2145) suggests replacing the `[@]` part by `[*]` in the above. This obviously breaks for filenames with spaces.

Comment: Defining `gitCmd=( git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -rf --cached [MAGIC]' HEAD )` and doing an array expansion `"${gitCmd[@]}"` doesn't work? It preserves the quoted expressions as defined. You can see the part within the quotes is not broken and preserved

Answer (score 5):

1. Instead of an array, use `set -- file1 file2 ...` to fill the parameter list, then use `bash` *parameter transformation* with the ***`Q`****uote* operator:

   ```
   set -- 'a "b' c "d 'e" "f 'g "'"h' ; (set -x; printf 'cmd %s\n' "${*@Q}")
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   + printf 'cmd %s\n' ''\''a "b'\'' '\''c'\'' '\''d '\''\'\'''\''e'\'' '\''f '\''\'\'''\''g "h'\'''
   cmd 'a "b' 'c' 'd '\''e' 'f '\''g "h'
   ```

   Or, if we remove the `set -x;`  part, the output becomes:

   ```
   cmd 'a "b' 'c' 'd '\''e' 'f '\''g "h'
   ```
2. [A comment from *LL3*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/518012/correctly-quote-array-that-is-being-passed-indirectly-via-another-command/518098?noredirect=1#comment957264_518098) suggests a better way that doesn't require
   `set -- ...`:

   ```
   export x; n=(a "b 'c"); x="${n[@]@Q}"
   ( n=($x); printf 'cmd %s\n' "${n[*]}"; )
   ```

   Simple version:

   ```bsh
   n=(a "b 'c"); echo "cmd ${n[@]@Q}"
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   cmd 'a' 'b '\''c'
   ```
3. Yet another method is to use `bash` *parameter transformation* with
   the ***`A`****ssignment* operator, (which also needs an `eval`):

   ```
   export x;n=(a b 'c d');x="${n[@]@A}"; (eval "$x";printf '%s\n' "${n[@]}")
   ```

   Output showing what `printf` sees:

   ```
   a
   b
   c d
   ```

Comment: Uh that's cool! I didn't know of that parameter expansion. I think you could then use it from the array itself and expand it directly on the command ? Something like `cmd "${files[*]@Q}"` (thus without passing through `set --` etc.)

Comment: @LL3 That's a good idea.  See revised answer.

Comment: My real use case is a parameter array rather than a regular array anyway, so I wouldn’t need `set --` either way, but having these solutions is brilliant.

Comment: Actually when trying to use this with my actual command I’m getting a “bad substitution” error: `git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch'"${*@D}" HEAD` — any idea why? This is on GNU bash 4.4.19(1)

Comment: @LL3 `D` was a typo, same result with `Q`. As mentioned previously, my “array variable” is actually the (function’s) argument array, `$@`. I can of course assign it to an array variable and use that but I thought it should work directly. I did try `"${@@Q}"`, which didn’t work: It still splits the `printf` command line.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, As a diagnostic please try: `set -- a b 'c d' ; (echo ${@@Q})`; it should print `'a' 'b' 'c d'`.

Comment: @agc That works. But it seems that putting additional quotes around `${@@Q}` is simply disregarded.

Comment: _"Instead of an array, (which can't be passed to a subshell)"_ -- Of course you can pass an array to a subshell, something like `a=('a b' c); (printf "cmd "; printf "%s " "${a[@]@Q}"; printf "\n")` works just fine and prints `cmd 'a b' 'c' `, which seems to be what is required. You can't pass an array through the environment to another process, though. But I'm not sure you need to do that here, whatever the argument to `--index-filter` is going to be, it can be made a single string in the main shell.

Comment: @ilkkachu, Your comment might make a good answer.  And I might be confusing as to the distinction between *a subshell* and *another process*; if you know of some question which explains the distinction, please post the URL.

Comment: bonus points: add quotes only when needed. `${n[@]@Q}` will always add single quotes

Answer (score 3):

`git filter-branch` runs `/bin/sh /usr/lib/git-core/git-filter-branch` and that script [evaluates the argument of  `--index-filter` using `eval`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/676c7e50b10f1fbb2ce06e46260f15f3a20679f7/git-filter-branch.sh#L425).

So that argument is evaluated as `/bin/sh` code.

On most systems, `/bin/sh` will be more or less an interpreter of the POSIX `sh` language, though in a few like Solaris 10 and older, it could still be the ancient Bourne `sh` language instead.

When it comes to quoting syntax, it makes little difference though.

In any case, none of the ksh/bash/zsh extended quoting operators like `$'...'` can be used. What that means is that you can't use GNU/bash/zsh/ksh `printf %q` or `mksh/bash` `${var@Q}` operator, or the `xtrace` tracing to generate the quoting as those resort to `$'...'` in some cases. They also use some forms of quoting that are not localisation-safe (like `\`).

One builtin quoting operator you could use is `zsh`'s `qq` parameter expansion flag as it uses single quotes:

```
files=(foo 'a b c' $'a\nb\nc' --foo-- "a'b")
git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached -- ${${(@qq)files}}" HEAD
```

To see how `zsh` quotes those:

```
$ printf '<%s>\n' "${${(@qq)files}}"
<'foo' 'a b c' 'a
b
c' '--foo--' 'a'\''b'>
```

With bash/ksh/yash/zsh, you could do that same quoting using a function like:

```
shquote() {
  LC_ALL=C awk -v q=\' '
    BEGIN{
      for (i=1; i<ARGC; i++) {
        gsub(q, q "\\" q q, ARGV[i])
        printf "%s ", q ARGV[i] q
      }
      print ""
    }' "$@"
}
```

And then:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached -- $(shquote "${files[@]}")" HEAD
```

Answer (score 2):

In Zsh there are several options for quoting. The best are the `(q+)` or `(q-)` expansion flags documented in `zshall(1)`. These add fewer unnecessary characters:

```
$ cmd=(ssh localhost "echo hi > t")

$ newcmd=(sh -c "${${(q@)cmd}}"); echo "${${(q@)newcmd}}"
sh -c ssh\ localhost\ echo\\ hi\\ \\>\\ t

$ newcmd=(sh -c "${${(qq@)cmd}}"); echo "${${(qq@)newcmd}}"
'sh' '-c' ''\''ssh'\'' '\''localhost'\'' '\''echo hi > t'\'''

$ newcmd=(sh -c "${${(q-@)cmd}}"); echo "${${(q-@)newcmd}}"
sh -c 'ssh localhost '\''echo hi > t'\'

$ newcmd=(sh -c "${${(qqqq@)cmd}}"); echo "${${(qqqq@)newcmd}}"
$'sh' $'-c' $'$\'ssh\' $\'localhost\' $\'echo hi > t\''
```

As for the syntax of `"${${(q@)cmd}}"`, the `q` (or `qq`, `q-` etc.) causes escaping or quoting to be applied. The `@` causes this escaping to applied to each element of the array `cmd`. The outer `${...}` seems to be equivalent to `${(j: :)...}`, i.e. joining with spaces. The double quotes are needed so that the result is not split again.

Unfortunately all of the quoting mechanisms in Zsh and Bash are exponential in quote depth for some inputs.

Here is an example showing the growth rate for the various quote expansion operators (code below):

```
q: (1) 6; (2) 14; (3) 24; (4) 42; (5) 76; (6) 142; (7) 272; (8) 530; 
qq: (1) 5; (2) 15; (3) 43; (4) 125; (5) 369; (6) 1099; (7) 3287; (8) 9849; 
qqq: (1) 5; (2) 13; (3) 25; (4) 45; (5) 81; (6) 149; (7) 281; (8) 541; 
qqqq: (1) 6; (2) 14; (3) 24; (4) 39; (5) 64; (6) 109; (7) 194; (8) 359; 
q-: (1) 5; (2) 15; (3) 39; (4) 97; (5) 237; (6) 575; (7) 1391; (8) 3361; 
q+: (1) 6; (2) 16; (3) 40; (4) 98; (5) 238; (6) 576; (7) 1392; (8) 3362;
```

Strangely `qqqq` grows the most slowly, even though it doesn't start to fall behind until the 4th level of nesting.

Tcl is a great language that has nested quote operators with linear growth properties (see item 6 under `man tcl`).

Here is the code for the experiments. I used `$'\t'` as the initial string because it gives different lengths for `q+` and `q-`.

```
f (){
  flag=$1
  echo -n "$flag: "
  str=$'\t'
  for i in $(seq 1 10); do
    eval 'str=\"${${('$flag'@)str}}\"'
    N=$(echo -n $str | wc -c)
    echo -n "($i) $N; "
  done
  echo
}
f q
f qq
f qqq
f qqqq
f q-
f q+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ foo=(1 2 '3 4' 4 5)
$ printf "'%s'\n" "${foo[@]}"
'1'
'2'
'3 4'
'4'
'5'
$ subcommand() { printf "'%s'\n" "$@"; }
$ subcommand "${foo[@]}"
'1'
'2'
'3 4'
'4'
'5'
```

So let's adapt this to your specific use-case:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter \
    'git rm -rf --cached file1 file2 […]' \
    HEAD
```

In your case we need to be a little more creative though, and break things up into smaller pieces.

```
git filter-branch --index-filter  \
    'git rm -rf --cached [MAGIC]' \
    HEAD
```

The file list we're creating is where you need the "magic" to happen.  The rest is all static, yes?  And since you're scripting this, you don't *need* it to be on three lines, which simplifies things:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -rf --cached [MAGIC]' HEAD
```

So:

```
prefix="git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -rf --cached "
postfix="' HEAD"
magic="$(printf '"%s" ' "${file[@]}"'
```

And then if we execute:

```
${prefix}${magic}${postfix}
```

Thereby, we have assembled your command - albeit using `"`s to enclose your filenames rather than `'`s, since the `filter-branch` command is in `'`s already.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn’t help me … In the `printf` code, I need all items in *one* line, properly quoted. Consider my actual use-case: your command would break the `git filter-branch` call.

Comment: So don't use `\n`, that was just for demonstrative purposes.  e. g. `printf "'%s' " "$@"`.

Comment: Again, consider my *actual* use-case. I’m using `\n` in the `printf` example because this emulates what the `git filter-branch` command is doing. The issue isn’t the newline, it’s that shell quoting doesn’t work inside a string.

Comment: So considered; see expanded discussion.

Comment: This is a nice enough hack and I think it does work with spaces — but unlike normal shell quoting it’s *not* generally valid. For instance, it fails if a filename contains a double-quote (crazy, but valid). I don’t think this issue can be worked around by using `printf`.